# Open SQLITE read-only in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite, connection-string, readonly

I trying to open an [SQLITE](http://www.sqlite.org/) database in read-only mode according this link:[Connection strings for SQLite](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlite)

**SQLITE Connection string**

```
string ConString = string.Format(@"Data Source={0}dbname.s3db;Version=3;New=False;Compress=True;Mode = Read Only;Temp Path={1};"
                , System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,TempPath); 

            using (SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(ConString))
            {
                    //Rerun Exception
                    connection.Open();
```

Exception:

> Valid parameters: Data Source=  (required)
>   Version=  (default: 2) New=True|False 
>   (default: False) Compress=True|False  (default: False)
>   UTF8Encoding=True|False  (default: False)

according [Opening A New Database Connection](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html) by setting read-only mode with the `SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY` flag can open database in read only mode,but dose any one done it in c#?

Comment: According to the link you provided it should be "Read Only=True" instead of "Mode = Read Only".

Comment: @Adrian Faciu:i tried that also but not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just burn my application on CD and it's work on `read-only` mode.

It's seems this is not required to set mode `read only` for read only device like CD or DVD,its work fine:)